# How I can prevent line break after codeigniter error message?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code for error messages:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
}
```

I show errors in template like this:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
    <script>
         Swal.fire('', '<div id="notification"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></div>', 'error');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But problem is on output:

```
<script>
Swal.fire('', '<div id="notification">Movie ID field is required!
</div>', 'error');
</script>
```

Need to be :

```
<script>
Swal.fire('', '<div id="notification">Movie ID field is required!</div>', 'error');
</script>
```

How I can prevent new line after message? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip out all the newlines from the output with `str_replace`

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
    <script>
         Swal.fire('', '<div id="notification"><?php echo str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', trim($this->session->flashdata('error'))); ?></div>', 'error');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```